# Using Custom HTML Properties in Meteor with React

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

Using React with Meteor, how can I render a HTML tag with custom properties?

For example,

```
<div class="page-header-image" data-parallax="true" filter-color="orange" style="background-image: url('./assets/img/header.jpg');">
```

has custom property `filter-color="orange"` which we want to render using the `render` function of a Reat.Component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="page-header-image" filter-color="orange" style={ {backgroundImage: "url('./assets/img/header.jpg')"} }></div>   
        );
    }
}
```

Also, is there a neat way to include these properties especially when you have many tags with custom HTML properties?

Comment: *"Using React with Meteor, how can I create a HTML tag with custom properties?"* - you mean a React component?

Comment: Yup using the `render` function of a React component. Updated the question to make it clearer, thanks

Comment: Wait, so you want to know how to use data  attributes in React? `<div data-parallax="true">` works.

Comment: @AndrewLi Sorry bad example. It should be something like `filter-color="orange"` that I want to add to the HTML tag

Comment: Then camelCase it: `filterColor="orange"`, that's the convention.

Comment: @AndrewLi Tried it and the HTML tag generated does not contain the attributes `filter-color` or `filterColor`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot you're trying to put it on an HTML element. Invalid attributes won't show. Just use a data attribute... `data-filterColor`

Comment: @AndrewLi Edited the css stye definition to use `data-filter-color` instead of `filter-color`, and your suggested approach works. Thanks!